# Does Adobe Brackets maintain any kind of history of search and replace expressions?

Tags: replace, adobe-brackets

Just now I was working on a fancy search and replace regular expression.

It looked good so I tested it on one entry then went to the editing area and the search and replace box went away.

I reopened the search and replace box to continue, but the selected text in the edit window replaced my search expression.

Control Z in the search box did not go back to my regex but undid the last change in the editing area.

I can't seem to find a way to get back to previous regexes in the find box. Is there any way? Googling turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Adobe Brackets doesn't maintain any kind of history of search and replace expressions. The feature is still missing.

Comment: You can upvote it on the Brackets feature backlog: https://trello.com/c/IzACddEv/344-s-find-recent-search-history.  The team takes these votes into account when deciding what to work on next.